# open the existing form dynamically using string in c #

Tags: c#

I'm trying to open forms which are dynamically attached in a menustrip .

Here my code is:

Form `frm`;

```
string formName =((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Text;
formName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name + "." + formName;

Type type = Type.GetType(formName);
frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);           

frm.Show();
```

Here the problem is. I'm geting `null` value to the type. Please help me in this task.

Comment: You need to make sure `formName` is correct (it must be the fully qualified type name, i.e. if you want a `string` you have to pass `System.String`), then your code will work

Comment: I would suggest an interface or a delegate implemenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up the assembly name (`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name`) and the namespace.

You need to find the real fully qualified class name of the form. If you know the namespace (i.e. the namespace is always the same for all forms) you can simply hard-code it. Another solution would be to use reflection to enumerate all types in the  `GetEntryAssembly` assembly and then check whether the type represents the form with the given name.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know the fully qualified name, you can iterate the types in your assembly and find the one you are interested in.

```
var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        where t.IsClass && t.Name.Equals(formname) && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form))
        select t;
```